# Take 100% width in FlatList - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a component named "AddWater" in which I want to display a FlatList with two columns. Everything is working but the component in FlatList is not consuming the entire space. Help me solve this issue.

I want the two components to take up 100% width which means one component take 50% space.

I am using react-native-paper for Card component and testing this in expo web

Check the code below.

```js
export default function AddWater() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        numColumns={2}
        data={sizes}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <Card style={styles.card}>
            <Card.Content>
              <Title>{item.size}</Title>
            </Card.Content>
          </Card>)
        }>

      </FlatList>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  card: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Comment: you want each Card element of Flatlist to take the entire height of the parent container?

Comment: I meant the entire width

Comment: posted the answer, do check out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `onLayout` props to get the width of the parent component and use that width for the `Card` element.

Here is the full working example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/thoughtful-salsa)

[image]

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card, Title } from 'react-native-paper';

const data = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
export default function App() {
  const [layout, setLayout] = useState({
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  });
  return (
    <View
      style={styles.container}
      onLayout={(event) => setLayout(event.nativeEvent.layout)}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Card
            style={{
              width: layout.width,
              backgroundColor: 'pink',
              marginTop: 20,
            }}>
            <Card.Content>
              <Title>{item}</Title>
            </Card.Content>
          </Card>
        )}></FlatList>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 22,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

Comment: It is now working when the flex of card is set to 1

Comment: you might be looking at result at the ```web``` tab, see the results on the android or iPhone tab.

Comment: Why is this working differently in web and android? Shouldn't it behave the same way

Comment: Maybe the underlying logic for determining the dimensions of the screen is only supported for android and iPhone devices and not the browser. They might change it in near future, but as of now it does not work for web.

Answer (score 1):

set numColumns={1} instead of 2

Comment: Why would someone want to do this when they want 2 columns